# Website height > 100%

Tags: css

I just started my website yesterday, trying out different things so I can apply them later on when I actually start making websites for companies etc. Anyway, I was wondering what is wrong with my code. I want my website to be 100% in height. I got it sorted out at first, but when I applied a transparant background image for the div 'content' the website's height wasn't 100% anymore. (You need to scroll to get to the bottom of the page). Could anyone help me solving this problem? Your help is appreciated! (I already looked up tons of earlier asked questions, but they did not have the answer I am looking for.)

```
html { 
          background: url('http://i.imgur.com/dbg9grg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          height: 100%;
        }

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;   
}

#Header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 

}

#logo {
    Width: 25%;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/rm9FZh0.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#song {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 20px;   
}
```

And the HTML: (If required)

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" href="index.html" />
    </div> <!-- close logo -->
</div> <!-- close Header -->

<div id="content">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="visit.html">Visit Tromsø</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- close nav -->
<div id="song">

<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">  
   <source src="music.ogg" />  
   <source src="music.mp3" />  
</audio> 

</div> <!-- close song -->
</div> <!-- close content -->
```

The CSS I pasted down there isn't the whole thing, but I am almost sure the 'nav' does not have an effect on the height of the page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @umesh: No! How on Earth is that going to help him? It will hide his content!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your child element is larger than the `body`.

Your `#content` has `height: 100%`, but not only it's not the only `div` in your `body` but it also has margins and paddings.

When you set `height: 100%` of a child element, it's height will be equal to the height of its parent (before applying margins and paddings). So `#content` is at least as tall as body, and therefore your whole page is taller than that.

You need to fix that accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the height was 100% + 75px. I just googled '100% height minus header' and found many topics about this problem. I am sure I will find an answer between those topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;   
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/dbg9grg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please always give an explanation. Also, I don't think this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete height and min-height from content.

So you only need:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/rm9FZh0.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given height: 100% to your html, that's fine, but then you gave height 100% to your content div
Now

```
total height = (Content div height(100%) + other content height) 
total height > height of html.
```

That's y you got a scroller.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is set to full height, so it is being pushed down by the 75px header. If your browser support allows you to use `calc` (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), you could modify your `#content` CSS like this:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/rm9FZh0.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 95%; // fallback for unsupported browsers - use an approximation.
    min-height: calc(100%-75px);
}
```

I've removed the `height` as redundant, but if you need it, you could use `calc` with that the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but 'calc' isn't supported by all browsers and it might be buggy, so I wont use it. I didn't know about it though, thanks for introducing it to me!